# Understanding this keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print below Javascript code and it displays `true` for first line and `false` for second line. Even though they both look the same, I do not understand their difference

```js
var someObj = {
  data: function() {
    console.log(this == someObj) // true
    console.log("Value of this " + this == someObj) //false
  }
};

someObj.data();
```

Comment: To help you understand the answers, here is a table of [JavaScript operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). tl;dr: `+` has higher precedence than `==`. Since your username is "JavaGeek", I would also note that Java and JavaScript and a number of other languages such as C and C++ all follow the same basic rules of operator precedence.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks and it helped me..

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad that was helpful.

Comment: Prompted by the title of your question, I've expanded my answer below with some additional information about the keyword `this` in Javascript. If you're coming from an OOP background (just taking a wild guess based on your username :)) it's definitely worth reading up on the concept of `this` in Javascript to understand how crazy, strange, and sometimes completely unpredictable it can be compared to what you might be used to from Java. Check out the link I've added to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `+` is concatenating the string to the toString of the object so you are comparing:

```
("Value of this " + this) == someObj
```

instead of

```
"Value of this " + (this == someObj)
```

```js
var someObj = {
  data: function() {
    console.log(this == someObj) // true
    console.log("Value of this " + this == someObj) // false
    console.log("Value of this " + (this == someObj)) // true
  }
};

someObj.data();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason `console.log("Value of this " + this == someObj) //false` result in false is because the concate `+` operator has highest precedence than the comparative operator `==`. To get the desired result you can separate the precedence by using parenthesis like,

```js
var someObj = {
  data: function() {
    console.log(this == someObj) // true
    console.log("Value of this " + (this == someObj)) //true
  }
};

someObj.data();
```

For better clarification here is the [javascript opearator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) table which you can consider.

Answer (score 1):

The second line is being parsed as:

`("Value of this " + this) == someObj`

And essentially evaluated to:

`("Value of this " + this.toString()) == someObj`

So on the left side you have a string, and on the right side an object, hence the inequality.

---

As a side note, your specific question here is more about how that line is getting parsed (the order of evaluation, the implicit `.toString()` conversion and concatenation that's taking place) and less about the keyword `this`. Now, the topic of `this` in Javascript is a whole lesson on its own, and quite different than what you might be used to from Java, C#, or other Object Oriented Languages. Definitely worth reading up on if you're coming to the wonderful world of Javascript (which is a non-OOP language) from one of those OOP languages. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

As somebody who coded in C# for a long time, I constantly have to remind myself that Javascript is a language of `prototype`s, `function`s, and `object literal`s. Methods are just like properties, and they can be passed around, bound to, and executed within different objects and contexts at any time. And `this` is quite different!

Answer (score 0):

The use of the keyword this is the one of the toughest things in javascript to understand how it works, the use of this references mean different things depending upon how or where it is called; it also gets muddied a bit compared to a class based language like Java. The this keyword references the context in which it is called. The way that it is referenced has led to solutions like bind() for callback functions it gets even more confusing with asynchronous operations. Now arrow functions ()=> {someObject} implicitly bind the this keyword to the context that contains the call regardless if the context has passed when it is executed, as can be the case in asynchronous operations.
As to the reference of the case comparison you aren't understanding in your code is how JavaScript operates as a language when it comes to loose comparison operator and has very little to do with the keyword this.

```
var someObj = {
data: function() {
console.log(this == someObj)
```

The line above is true because the context of 'this' is someObj so this === someObj

```
console.log("Value of this " + this == someObj) // false
```

The line above is false because you are concatenating the object this to the "Value of this " so the toString method is called and JavaScript converts someObj to a String in order to perform a comparison and the String on the right side does not equal the string on the left side therefore the value is false

```
console.log("Value of this " + (this == someObj)) // true
```

The statement above once again compares the 'this' object to someObj and they both reference the same object so you can expect the console to log  Value of this true

If you would like to learn more about the this keyword here is a link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
If you would like to learn more about the loose comparison operator versus the strict comparison operator here is a link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

I hope this clears things up a little